# When to use foreach loop for retrieving data from relational database and when not to

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, relational-database, laravel-8

Currently I have finished my project which is a *Movie Storage* with Laravel 8 and for this project, I tried to apply these relationships:

```
Movie AND Actor : Many To Many

Movie AND Director : Many To One

Movie AND IMDB : One To One

Movie AND Genre : Many To Many
```

And I have applied the relationships to their Models as well and also can get the data from the DB properly:

```
@foreach(\App\Models\Movie::all() as $movie)
<tr>
    <th scope="row">{{ ++$menuCounter }}</th>
    <td><a href="{{ $movie->link }}">{{ $movie->name }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ $movie->year }}</td>
    <td>
        @foreach($movie->actors as $actor)
            {{ $actor->name }}
        @endforeach
    </td>
    <td>
        @foreach($movie->genres as $genre)
            {{ $genre->name }}
        @endforeach
    </td>
    <td>{{ $movie->imdb->rate }}</td>
    <td>{{ $movie->director->name }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

But I have a question running on my head which is:

**When and at what cases I have to use `foreach` loop to get the data and when not to use `foreach` ?**

For example if I say `{{ $movie->genres->name }}` instead of using `foreach` loop, I will get this error:

> **Exception** Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance

However this array already exists if I try `$movie->genres`:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Thriller",
        "created_at": "2021-05-01T11:17:24.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-05-01T11:17:24.000000Z",
        "pivot": {
            "movie_id": 9,
            "genre_id": 2
        }
    }
]
```

So do I need to use `foreach` for ManyToMany relationships ? At what cases I can straightly use the method written in the Model and call the property like `$movie->genres->name` ?

I know this question is kinda weird, but I need to make this thing clear in my head...

Comment: I don't really understand the question. When you have collections, you need to iterate them. If you're sure a collection only has one element, then fetch the first element and access the properties on it.

Comment: On a different note: do you understand why `{{ $movie->genres->name }}` didn't work in your case here?

Comment: @El_Vanja Not really !

Comment: @El_Vanja They say maybe some of the data does not have `name`, but in fact they all have one

Comment: Because `$movie->genres` is not an instance of your Genre model. It's an instance of a Collection object, whose *elements* are instances of Genre. Think of it like an array of objects. You can't access an object property on the array itself. You need to first get the specific object to access its property.

Comment: @El_Vanja So why `$movie->director->name` works fine ?

Comment: simply we can say .. you want to access data that have  hasmany or many to many relationship with other models.. then you need to use foreach ,, because you are retrieving has many relations(data),,, example actors with movies

Comment: Depends on how you define the relationship. If it's *-to-one, you get the instance of your model. If it's *-to-many, you get a collection.

Comment: Let me also add some tips: never do `\App\Models\Movie::all()`, you can have `10000` and that is going to explode anyone's PC (when viewing the content), especially your server, you should use [`chunk`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#chunking-results) and no more than 100 per call, also, because you have relations, you are having a query issue, you are running more queries than you should, to solve this issue, you can use [`with`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) (it is called `Eager Loading`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know this question is kinda weird, but I need to make this thing clear in my head...

The question is a simple, straight-forward one, but it has become complicated due to (a) a bad data model or bad DDL, and (b) the several levels of implementation concerns.  Let me answer it from the top, down, rather than from the bottom, up, which is the way you perceive it.

#### RDBMS • Set Processing

Codd's *Relational Model*, is entirely set-based.  SQL (genuine, the Standard) is the rendition of the Data Sublanguage defined in the *RM*, and it is entirely set-based.  Set Processing is extremely fast.

- Therefore one should always and only use Set Processing commands in SQL

#### RDBMS • Procedural Processing

Aka row-by-row processing; aka `foreach` processing.  There are a very few circumstances in which this sort of processing is permitted against a Relational database, eg. MonthEnd procedure for a bank, when all accounts are tallied for the month, and a month-end figure is determined.  Procedural Processing is extremely slow.

- Any other Procedural processing would place the coder back in the 1960's
- A `cursor` is Procedural processing.

#### Non-RDBMS

Typically the freeware (a) misuses the term "sql", and (b) has no architecture and thus no proper segregation of functions, let alone depth and maturity in such functions.  Thus:

- it just cannot perform Set Processing when more than a few tables are given, or
- it cannot figure out how to parse a JOIN of several tables, and to construct an efficient `QueryPlan`.

Which some programmers work around, by either tweaking the SQL to obtain better performance, or resorting to `foreach` processing.

#### Bad Data Model/DDL/Additional Layer

The second typical problem is an incorrect specification of the tables, at either the modelling or DDL (good model, bad DDL) or Layer (good DDL, bad layer spec).  Eg. errors such as:

> Exception Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance

Which causes the Set Processing attempt to fail, and the developer resorts to procedural processing.

The proper correction is of course, to fix the Model/DDL/Layer, so that you obtain Set Processing and speed.

> So do I need to use `foreach` for ManyToMany relationships ? At what cases I can straightly use the method written in the Model and call the property like `$movie->genres->name` ?

I am not a Laravel expert (never had the need, because I use Commercial SQL Platforms), but that is the typical limitation in the additional layer.  You can get around it by understanding the layer, and fiddling with the code, until it works.  As per the comments.

I do not know if Laravel can do genuine Set Processing (from this example it appears unlikely).